# dynamodb deleteItem works, but it's callback returning undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a deleteItem lambda function I created that deletes an item if it's userId is found. The userId is passed as a `pathParameter` and it works no problem if the userId is found.

```
let output = await deleteUser(userId);
console.log("output: " + JSON.stringify(output))
```

always returns `output: undefined`

everytime whether it's found and deleted or not. I need a response from the `deleteItem` operation so that I can return message `User not found` or `User deleted` based on that response.

How can I get the dynamodb callback to work properly?

delete.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const tableName = process.env.TABLE_NAME;

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    let userId = event.pathParameters.userid;

    try {
        let output = await deleteUser(userId);
        console.log("output: " + JSON.stringify(output))
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: "User deleted"
            })
        };


    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR TIME")
        console.log("ERROR:" + err)

        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: "User failed to be deleted"
            })
        };

    }


    async function deleteUser(userId) {
        let params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            "Key": {
                "userid": {
                    "S": userId.toString()
                }
            }
        };
        try {
            const dbResponse = await dynamoDB.deleteItem(params).promise();

            console.log("dbResponse")
            console.log(dbResponse)

            if (dbResponse.Item) {
                console.log(`deleted row with userId of ${userId}`);
                return (dbResponse);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`user reset failed with ${err}`);
            return {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    errr: err
                })
            };
        }
    }


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `dbResponse` doesn't have a property named `Item`, so this condition is never satisfied:

```
 if (dbResponse.Item) {
```

I suggest reviewing [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#deleteItem-property) to see what the expected response format is, or at the very least log `dbResponse` so you can see what is coming back.

Comment: I added a console log under ```const dbResponse = await dynamoDB.deleteItem(params).promise();``` in original question to demonstrate. The first time I attempted to delete a userid that doesn't exist. The second time I deleted an item that does exist (successfully). Both times, the output of ```console.log(dbResponse)``` has been ```{}``` Even if Item isn't the property named, it should return something when performing the deleteItem operation. Do you have any suggestions of why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you think it should always return something? You aren't setting `ReturnConsumedCapacity`, `ReturnItemCollectionMetrics` or `ReturnValues`, so it isn't going to return anything. Please take the time to read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!